# UCanAccess upgrade Apache Commons Lang version

Tags: ucanaccess, jackcess

Can you upgrade your Apache Commons Lang 2.6 to Apache Commons Lang 3.5 ?

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether it is currently possible to use UCanAccess with Apache Commons Lang 3.x instead of 2.x, the answer is "No".

If you're asking whether UCanAccess can be modified to use Apache Commons Lang 3.x instead of 2.x, it's not really a matter of modifying UCanAccess. UCanAccess depends on Jackcess, and Jackcess depends on Commons Lang, so it's up to the Jackcess development team to decide if and when they want to make such a change.

Recently there was just such a [Feature Request for Jackcess](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/feature-requests/35/); you may want to leave a comment there to indicate your support.

Comment: @jaktao Should you have conflicting libraries in your app, you have you to import the   ucanaload.jar to your project (and none of the other jars). This library will load the other ones( including Apache Commons Lang) with a custom classloader avoiding conflicts, but you must let the UCanAccess directories structure AS IS in the distribution. Let me know if this is the case for further explainations.

Comment: In the "Feature Request for Jackcess" it says they are going to upgrade version to Apache Common Lang 3.x in the next version of Jackcess, it's perfect for me. My project includes Apache Common Lang 3.x and UCanAccess but these library don't have conflicts. It's only for health code. Thanks for your reply.